# Setting up development environment for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm from PHP background. I used to use Apache, MySQL and PHP for web development.
I'm just starting asp.net mvc.

1. I've Visual Studio 2008 Pro SP1 & .NET 3.5 SP1 already installed on my computer.
2. So, I installed **[ASP.NET MVC 1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en)**
3. Created a "ASP.NET MVC Web Application"  project
4. when I hit F5 it gives error **Unable to connect to the ASP.NET Development Server**

No wonder. In this process I didn't setup the webserver.

Can I use apache here? I guess IIS is the default. Where is it? How do I configure it? What is the WebRoot directory for IIS server? Where can I find it?

On searching for "Unable to connect to the ASP.NET Development Server"  I found this solution:

> Step 1: Select the “Tools->External
>   Tools” menu option in VS or Visual Web
>   Developer.  This will allow you to
>   configure and add new menu items to
>   your Tools menu.
>
> Step 2: Click the “Add” button to add
>   a new external tool menu item.  Name
>   it “WebServer on Port 8010” (or
>   anything else you want).
>
> Step 3: For the “Command” textbox
>   setting enter this value:
>   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\WebDev.WebServer.EXE
>   (note: this points to the web-server
>   that VS usually automatically runs).
>
> Step 4: For the “Arguments” textbox
>   setting enter this value: /port:8010
>   /path:$(ProjectDir) (or any port you
>   like)
>
> Step 5: Select the “Use Output Window”
>   checkbox (this will prevent the
>   command-shell window from popping up.
>
> Once you hit apply and ok you will
>   now have a new menu item in your
>   “Tools” menu called “WebServer on Port
>   8010”.  You can now select any web
>   project in your solution and then
>   choose this menu option to launch a
>   web-server that has a root site on
>   port 8010 (or whatever other port you
>   want) for the project. You can then
>   connect to this site in a browser by
>   simply saying http://localhost:8010/. 
>   All root based references will work
>   fine.
>
> Step 6: The last step is to configure
>   your web project to automatically
>   reference this web-server when you run
>   or debug a site instead of launching
>   the built-in web-server itself.  To-do
>   this, select your web-project in the
>   solution explorer, right click and
>   select “property pages”.  Select the
>   “start options” setting on the left,
>   and under server change the radio
>   button value from the default (which
>   is use built-in webserver) to instead
>   be “Use custom server”.  Then set the
>   Base URL value to be:
>   http://localhost:8010/

But there is no  `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\WebDev.WebServer.EXE` such file on my system. Did I forget to install something? Please help me in running my "Hello World" application.

**EDIT:**

I'm using Windows XP SP2  and logged in as a user with Administrative previlages.

from this [Unable to connect to ASP.Net Development Server issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990033/unable-to-connect-to-asp-net-development-server-issue)

> - Disable IPv6

Done!!

> - Make sure there isnt an edit in the hosts file for localhost

There is no single entry in my hosts file (%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts) with 'localhost' in it.

> - Check firewall/virus settings to allow connections to/from devenv.exe

I tried by disabling the firewall/antivirus

> - If you can preview in the browser make sure the URL in the browser uses the same port number as the port number shown in the ASP.NET dev server taskbar icon.

No, Actually there is no such dev server taskbar icon.

> - Try setting a fixed, predefined port in project properties

Tried it. But no positive result.

**Solution:**

After trying everything. I came to conclusion that WebDev.WebServer.exe may be corrupt. So, I've replaced `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\9.0\WebDev.WebServer.EXE` with a fresh copy : http://www.4shared.com/file/116555696/ff3b0dc8/WebDevWebServer.html

It worked!! :)

Comment: Which Windows are you using? Also, do you have administrative permissions? No, you can't use Apache here; the most common web server to use for ASP.NET development is the one you talk about; WebDev.WebServer.EXE; sometimes referred to as Cassini, which is a minimal ASP.NET web server that Visual Studio runs.

Comment: your final solution was the answer for me. I just took the WebDev.WebServer.EXE and WebDev.WebServer.EXE.manifest files from my C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 folder and copied them to the folder under Microsoft shared. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET Development Server is a mini web server that comes with Visual Studio.  The idea is that you wouldn't need to set up IIS for development.

Checkout this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990033/unable-to-connect-to-asp-net-development-server-issue) for possible solutions.  Mostly I would make sure that localhost is not redirected in your hosts file and also that you are not doing anything funky with a local firewall app that might be blocking certain ports on localhost.

You cannot, as far as I am aware, use Apache.  You could configure it to use IIS in your project Properties->Start Options screen by pointing it to a valid IIS directory you have set up.

**Edit:**
Also try this:

1. Open a command window (cmd.exe)
2. Run C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\9.0\WebDev.WebServer.Exe /port:8080 /path:c:\mywebpath\  (swap out c:\mywebpath for the path to your app)

You should notice the WebDev server start up in your task bar.  You should then be able to browse to http://localhost:8080/default.aspx (or whatever your page is).

If that doesn't work try the same thing but using http://127.0.0.1:8080/default.aspx.  If this works but localhost does not then something is redirecting your localhost traffic.

Comment: `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\WebDev.WebServer.EXE` is not existing on my system.

Comment: Mine is installed in : C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\9.0\ - do you have a WebDev.WebServer.EXE there?

Comment: Yeah found it in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\9.0\`. Still my problem is not solved. But Visual Studio is supposed to start this automatically and display the site in browser right? Other wise there is no use of VS2008. I could have used notepad or some intellisense editor to code website. Whats the user of VS2008?

Comment: Added more to the answer, following those steps should help troubleshoot - I still suspect that your may have something (possibly an entry in your hosts file) blocking localhost

Comment: What you are saying is same as adding external tools in visual studio. Anyway, I'm getting the same error `The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000007b). Click on OK to terminate the application.` this is also the same error I'm getting when I'm trying to set this as "External Tool"

Comment: Also, I've edited the query. Please check. No, there is no `localhost` entry in my hosts file.

Comment: I solved it. Just my C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\9.0\WebDev.WebServer.EXE was corrupt!! I replaced it with the original copy & it worked.