# Visual Studio crashes during runtime

Tags: visual-studio-2010, devexpress

Please can you help me with this VS 2010 issue. This issue comes out every time I want to run my project. Can it be fixed somehow? The screen shot isi aviable in attached file.
[image]

Comment: possiable duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990033/unable-to-connect-to-asp-net-development-server-issue

Comment: please find answer here  on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096628/setting-up-development-environment-for-asp-net-mvc

Comment: no, it's not fresh installed. Ok, thanks, I'll check out your solution and I'll let you know

Comment: does the problem occurs in this project only or other projects as well?

Comment: terminating the "WebDev.WebServer40.EXE" process didn't help. this isuue comes out in every project :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try registring IIS again...To do this follow the given steps...

1. go to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.X folder from Command prompt
2. execute aspnet_regiis.exe -I command from  Command prompt

close the Visual studio and re-open.

Try re-run the project again.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much! but it didn't help :( Can't imagine what can occur this isuue

Comment: Jigar Pandya Thank yuo! your solution worked, only after windows restart!

Comment: gud guud ;) Keep going best of luck on stackoverflow