# Unable to connect to ASP.NET development server error visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, iis

When I am trying to run my asp.net project it is giving me error as:

"Unable to connect to ASP.NET development server error."

It was working well one day ago, **but after I uninstalled and re-installed Visual Studio**, now it is showing me Error in visual studio.I have no idea about this error please help me in this regard. Any help regarding this will be strongly appreciated.

Comment: I think we're going to need more information to help you here.

Comment: its problem with my visual studio.I uninstalled my visual studio and the reinstalled it.But it didnt help.Same error comes agian.

Comment: Are you running a firewall on your local machine?  Have you tried disabling that and trying again to run your project?

Comment: yes my firewell is turned off @gregD but thx for trying....

Comment: This might help!
[Setting up development environment for ASP.NET MVC]


  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096628/setting-up-development-environment-for-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced this problem. while installing the visual studio 2010 we need to install IIS component.Follow the steps for installing "IIS 6 management capability".
1.goto control panel>>Turned windows features on or OFF>>
2.Internet information services >> web management tools>> check out checkbox (IIS management console)