# vs2010 unable to connect to the ASP.net development server

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2010

i am getting this error while trying to view in browser. i checked the host file and the 127.0.0.1       localhost line wasn't commented

i am on windows server 2003 and my IIS is working fine as projects on VS2008 are working fine

i am really confused and trapped in this.

Comment: any solution about it ?

Answer (score 1):

If this worked before and now it doesn't the WebDev.WebServer40 process is likely still resident.  Open the task manager and kill the process called "WebDev.WebServer40.EXE"

Beau posted this originally [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990033/unable-to-connect-to-asp-net-development-server-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the project and check Properties -> Web.

Personally I've found the most reliable way to set-up is to select 'Use Custom Web Server' and put a valid local URL in there (e.g. http://MyTestWebApp.local)

You'll also need to map this url to localhost (127.0.0.1) in your hosts file and make the neccessary changes to the bindings for the site in IIS.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've just faced the issue today. After reading this thread and some similar ones I found out that my COMODO firewall was the real cause. I had blocked "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" and this caused the issue. 
Since I still want it to be blocked I've edited the firewall policy to allow outbound connections from devenv.exe to 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and similar to what Joe Johnston said , I killed WebDev.WebServer20.EXE
then it worked just fine .