# visual studio 2008 run web application

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [unable to connect to ASP.Net development server issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990033/unable-to-connect-to-asp-net-development-server-issue)

Hi,

I get an error while trying to run web applications,

Error Message:
      **Unable to connect to the ASP.NET Development Server.**

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely something else is using the ports needed by the ASP.NET Development Server.  Check out this link for more information:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1189567.aspx/1?Unable+to+connect+to+the+ASP+NET+Development+Server

Basically, when you look down through the solutions posted there, you find it could be a port in use, a folder in an unexpected place (64-bit machine), an anti-virus software or firewall blocking the port, etc.  There is a lot of possible causes so you will need to experiment but this information should get you started.