# Unable to Connect to the ASP.NET Development Server VS2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I realise this question has been asked many times before and I've tried pretty much every solution out there but I still keep getting this annoying error.

I've tried killing off the WebDev.WebServer40 process as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990033/unable-to-connect-to-asp-net-development-server-issue). I've disabled IPv6 and my firewall, I've also looked inside my "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" folder for WebDev.WebServer and it doesn't exist in that directory, even when I download a fresh one and place it there it still doesn't work.

All my other web projects work fine and don't have this problem, but this particular Web Site keeps giving me this error when I try to run it.

I'm using VS2010 and .NET Framework 4.0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at making sure that the folder has appropriate permissions? I don't recall off hand, but that was my issue way back in the day.

Comment: Yes but that didn't seem to work either, so I just ended up creating a new solution and placing my old project files and pages in the new one and now it works fine, even my web.config is the same as before yet everything is working. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Replace `WebDev.WebServer.exe` with another exe
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\9.0\WebDev.WebServer.exe`
2. Restart your machine .

I tried every thing before restarting the machine but all failed.

You can use this exe from 
http://www.4shared.com/rar/4CXREKtb/WebDevWebServer.html

---

Answer (score 5):

Open the solution file with a text editor like Notepad++, there is a property of the solution called VWDPort, the value of this property is the port used to publish the website, delete the port leaving the property `VWDPort = "";` when you start debugging again, .Net will choose a new FREE port. Problem Solved!

Hope it helps

Comment: That's the real answer. Thanks!

Comment: After looking at a few dozen 'solutions', this - alone - was the answer.  Although I should note that terminating the WebDev.WebServer.EXE process is also a likely answer if that process is actually running.  Just FYI, TCPView (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) will let you see if something else is already trying to use the currently configured VWDPort and kill the process if appropriate.  Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem, what I did is I just terminate the "WebDev.WebServer40.EXE" process then restart the Project and its worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had to move my DevServer folder to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer` dir.
from its current location `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer`
After doing so the problem was fixed :)
Originally posted here by spankster:
http://forums.asp.net/post/2426735.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted my machine and it worked.