# "WebDev.WebServer20.exe has stopped working" with "Unable to Connect to the ASP.NET Development Server" VS 2008 only on specific project

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am getting "WebDev.WebServer20.exe has stopped working" with "Unable to Connect to the ASP.NET Development Server" VS 2008 only on a specific project.

other projects works fine. only this project throws the following errors when i click `Run`

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16837871/6082645), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11434301/6082645), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17393961/6082645) solutions. but not working. might be because of i am getting both errors consecutively

Is there a fix for that? or should i need go with creating a new project with the same name as an ultimate solution for project wise bugs :(

[image: WebDev.WebServer20.exe has stopped working]

after that

[image: Unable to Connect to the ASP.NET Development Server VS 2008]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Changing `Auto-assign Port` to `Specific Port` and giving some random
>   port number  makes the project to run and prevent from crashing
>   `WebDev.WebServer20.exe`.

Double click on `Solution Explorer -> My Project` in `Web` tab under `Servers` -> `Use Visual Studio Development Server` click radio button called `Specific Port` and change port number to some random value from `0 to 65535`, then save and `run`.