# ASP.NET MVC error message 'Unable to connect to the Visual Studio Development Server.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I'm programming with ASP.NET MVC. I tried to launch the application multiple times([Ctrl] + [F5]), restarted Visual Studio and restarted my PC, however I still get the error message 'Unable to connect to the Visual Studio Development Server.'
If I just press [F5] I get the error message 'This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.' 
How can I get rid of these errors?

Comment: Try ˋrun as administrator´ on VS.

Comment: Same issue. @Llazar

Comment: Then try to delete the .vs folder and restart again.

Comment: Still the same, it works for another project in my solution though. @Llazar

Comment: There is an other solution for this issue. Change the the port of your project. The number after locacalhost:ˋthis number´

Comment: Changed it in Properties --> Web --> Project Url, unfortunately still the same. @Llazar

Comment: With VS restart.

Comment: [F5] --> 'Localhost refused to connect.'
[Ctrl] + [F5] --> 'Unable to connect to the Visual Studio Development Server.'
@Llazar

Comment: This might help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990033/unable-to-connect-to-asp-net-development-server-issue

Comment: I deleted the project because it was for testing purposes only anyways. Recreated it and it works fine now. Thank you for your help anyways:) @Sajithd

Answer (score 1):

None of these solutions worked for me, If you have installed default Windows IIS (Which comes with your windows) and have access to it, try to use it, that solved my problem, simply Add new website or new application there and it's done, anyway it's weird that IIS Express is unable to open up the page. If you need to trace it, just attach it to a process using `ctrl + alt + p` short keys and check `Show process for all users` and select `w3wp.exe` (sometimes need to refresh the website in browser to find `w3wp.exe`) and then hit the `Attach` button, you'll be asked for run as administration if it has not been already run as administrator.